# @Named("cc") not being constructed when referenced in JSF page

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF file (characters.xhtml) that is not rendering properly, and I suspect it has to do with the backing bean (CharactersController) not being instantiated. I can render the page (meaning all the HTML code is generated), but without any details contained by the bean, such as my "msg" property data being displayed. At minimum, "msg" should display "hello", or ideally "list size is: 0".

Ultimately, I want to pull data from my database with this bean (the DAO itself works separately in a REST resource, so I don't think that is the problem). But as it stands, my CharactersController bean does not appear to be instantiating. I have a @PostConstruct that should log an output when the bean is created, but it is not appearing anywhere, which is why I suspect issue there.

On a related note, I have another managed bean for a different JSF file that does load correctly. It is also ViewScoped. I am able to see the log from its respective @PostConstruct. (From other older posts, ViewScoped may have been a culprit, but it doesn't seem to be here since it does work for my other bean.)

Lastly, I get a null pointer error if I try creating a component referencing any methods. I bring this up because I tried loading my data via <f:viewAction> tag.

Other details:
I'm using Jakarta EE 9, Glassfish 6.1 RC1, Java 11, IntelliJ, Maven build.
I do have getters and setters for all fields in CharactersController except for "dao". I omitted the code for brevity.

CharactersController - Managed Bean

```
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import xxx.dao.CharactersDao;
import xxx.CharactersEntity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Named("cc")
@ViewScoped
public class CharactersController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CharactersController() {
    }

    @Inject
    private CharactersDao dao;
    private List<CharactersEntity> chars;
    private CharactersEntity newChar;
    private String msg = "hello";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("CharactersController");

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        chars = dao.getAll();
        msg = "list size is: " + chars.size();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "CC constructed: " + msg);
    }
```

characters.xhtml - facelet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
>
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/adminTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="dataTable">

            <h3>Msg: <h:outputText value="#{cc.msg}"/></h3>
            <h:form>
                <h:dataTable value="#{cc.chars}" var="char">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Characters"/>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="ID"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{char.characterId}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Avatar"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{char.avatar}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{char.name}"/>
                    </h:column>


                </h:dataTable>

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

HTML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
    <title>RPG Admin</title></head><body>
    <header>
        <h1>admin</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="admin-nav-row">
            <div><a href="/rpg_xe/admin/home.xhtml">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div><a href="/rpg_xe/admin/characters.xhtml">Characters</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>

            <h3>Msg: </h3>
<form id="j_idt13" name="j_idt13" method="post" action="/rpg_xe/admin/characters.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt13" value="j_idt13" />
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Characters</th></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="col">ID</th>
<th scope="col">Avatar</th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="jakarta.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:jakarta.faces.ViewState:0" value="-7288672771663122896:-6269118426931924221" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
    </main>

    <footer>footer</footer></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but there is a builtin object already called "cc" (For composite component) But I don't know if there are any conflict here. Try changing the name anyway.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that was it! I changed the name and now it works. Thank you, I was really questioning myself there. I guess the big takeaway is to not be lazy with names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that you have confirmed:

"cc" cannot be used as a managed bean name because there is a conflict with builtin object "cc" (Composite Component).

"The word cc in JavaServer Faces is a reserved word for composite components."
https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-facelets005.html